# How can I clean up/remove the content in AppLayout in Vaadin 14?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

How can I show a static component in Vaadin 14? Every time I update the page, I get the error.

In this case, `startStopYOLO, cameras, darknet, configuration, weights, thresholds, realTimeCameraImage, layout` are all `static`

```
// Content
if(layout == null) {
    layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.add(new FormLayout(startStopYOLO, cameras, darknet, configuration, weights, thresholds));
    layout.add(realTimeCameraImage);
    layout.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
}
setContent(layout); // Here I get the error:
```

The error is:

```
Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree
```

So I need to clean up the `content` first. How can I do that in Vaadin 14?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error already states the problem to some extend: `Can't move a node from one state tree to another`

Or rather: you **can not share** elements over different UIs.  So no
`static`, no singletons, ... - you **have to** create fresh elements.

Elements becoming part of the scene graph for one UI (the *state tree*
from the error message) once they get *attached*.  At this point the
Vaadin internals make sure, the element is not already attached to
a different UI (root) (it's OK to move elements inside one UI, which
also works by adding it to a different parent of the same UI).

If you have shared state over e.g. the server, you will have to create
elements for each UI and then sync this state with `@Push` and
`UI.access` or alike.

Comment: No it's possible to have the components as statics.

Comment: Sure, but only for the following border case: it's possible as long exactly one client holds on the static element; e.g. by following the suggested steps in the error message (removing the element first). But if this is hardly your use-case.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson maybe, but you still cannot have a single component added multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: @kscherrer So I can't show an image at multiple users?

Comment: The same image.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Sure you can. You create different image **elements** that point all back to the same server resource/link/...

Comment: @cfrick I think I need to have to do that!

Comment: If your question is related to how to replace AppLayout content upon navigation to other view, check the example here: https://github.com/TatuLund/devday-demo-flow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/devday/demo/MainLayout.java#L260